# Using an object defined in one @interface in another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface

I've defined two @interfaces in a .h file for my iPhone app project and would like to use a NSMutableData object defined in one @interface in the other. Is this possible / how would I go about doing it?

Thanks!

---

Here's what my code looks like. The reason I have to add another delegate for the NSConnection is because this is the second connection being made (I haven't shown the code for the first connection).

```
@implementation SecondNSDownloadDelegate

@synthesize responseData;
@synthesize test;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:
  (NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(test) <-- gives null(), this is the problem.
[self.responseDataYears setLength:0];
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@class ViewController;
@class AnotherViewController;

@synthesize responseDataYears;
@synthesize test;

- (void)getAvailableYears {
NSString *test = @"test";
secondNSConnecterDelegate = [[SecondNSDownloadDelegate alloc] init];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest 
    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"data_url"]] 
    delegate:secondNSConnecterDelegate];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you want to access a value in another object you have to actually reference that object (with a pointer).

Comment: I think you should give this a read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a reference to the other interface:

```
@interface A 
@property (strong) NSMutableData *data;
@end


@interface B
@property (strong) A *a;
@end
```

then, somewhere in the implementation for B, access the data using

```
NSMutableData *data = self.a.data;
...
```

Tim

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Tim. This sort of works for me - I still can't edit in one interface and then retrieve those edits in the other. I tried with a simple string by setting it up with some initial value in the first interface and modifying its values in functions in the other interface. I just got the original string back, no modifications, however.

Comment: @LatifAlam Edit your question and post some code to show what you are doing. Remember that NSString is immutable...